# Is a "switch" the best to use in the following scenario?

Tags: php, switch-statement, short

I've got a long code in php, can it be made shorter by any other method using a `switch` or otherwise? I have a pay rate table and different states have different rates of the same designation. I want to insert an `array` of values in the table where there is a particular designation (`desg`) and `state` which then calculates the rate accordingly.

**Table:**

```
id  desgn      rate   state
1   MAZDOOR    6600   MN
2   SKD-I      10890  MN
3   SKD-I      11400  MZ
4   SKD-II     9270   MN
5   SKD-II     9300   MZ
```

**My script so far:**

```
if(!empty($_POST['u'])) {
    foreach ($_POST['u'] as $uid) {
        $sql=mysql_query("select * from cpl_pay_temp where id='$uid' ");

        while ($cal = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {

            $ticket=$cal['ticketno'];
            // $month_yr=$_POST['month'];
            $desgn=$cal['desg'];
            $empname=$cal['name'];
            $empdesg=$cal['desg'];
            $cat=$cal['sex'];
            $father=$cal['fathersname'];
            $present=$cal['day_present'];
            $state=$cal['state'];

            if(($desgn=='MAZDOOR')&& ($state=='MZ')) {
                $sql_rate=mysql_query("select * from cpl_rate_mast where desg='MAZDOOR' and state='MZ'");
                $rate=mysql_result($sql_rate,$i,'rate') ;
                $pay=round($present*($rate/$days)); 
            }

            if(($desgn=='MAZDOOR')&& ($state=='MN')) {
                $sql_rate=mysql_query("select * from cpl_rate_mast where desg='MAZDOOR' and state='MN'");
                $rate=mysql_result($sql_rate,$i,'rate') ;
                $pay=round($present*($rate/$days)); 
            } 

            if(($desgn=='SKD-I') && ($state=='MZ')){
                $sql_rate=mysql_query("select * from cpl_rate_mast where desg='SKD-I' and state='MZ'");
                $rate=mysql_result($sql_rate,$i,'rate') ;
                $pay=round($present*($rate/$days)); 
            }

            if(($desgn=='SKD-I') && ($state=='MN')) {
                $sql_rate=mysql_query("select * from cpl_rate_mast where desg='SKD-I' and state='MN'");
                $rate=mysql_result($sql_rate,$i,'rate') ;
                $pay=round($present*($rate/$days)); 
            }

            if(($desgn=='SKD-I') && ($state=='MZ')){
                $sql_rate=mysql_query("select * from cpl_rate_mast where desg='SKD-I' and state='MZ'");
                $rate=mysql_result($sql_rate,$i,'rate') ;
                $pay=round($present*($rate/$days)); 
            }

            if(($desgn=='SKD-II') && ($state=='MN')) {
                $sql_rate=mysql_query("select * from cpl_rate_mast where desg='SKD-II' and state='MN'");
                $rate=mysql_result($sql_rate,$i,'rate') ;
                $pay=round($present*($rate/$days)); 
            }

            if(($desgn=='SKD-II') && ($state=='MZ')) {
                $sql_rate=mysql_query("select * from cpl_rate_mast where desg='SKD-II' and state='MZ'");
                $rate=mysql_result($sql_rate,$i,'rate') ;
                $pay=round($present*($rate/$days)); 
            }

            if(($desgn=='SKD-III') && ($state=='MN')) {
                $sql_rate=mysql_query("select * from cpl_rate_mast where desg='SKD-III' and state='MN'");
                $rate=mysql_result($sql_rate,$i,'rate') ;
                $pay=round($present*($rate/$days)); 
            }

            if(($desgn=='SKD-III') && ($state=='MZ')) {
                $sql_rate=mysql_query("select * from cpl_rate_mast where desg='SKD-III' and state='MZ'");
                $rate=mysql_result($sql_rate,$i,'rate') ;
                $pay=round($present*($rate/$days)); 
            }

            if(($desgn=='HSKD') && ($state=='MN')){
                $sql_rate=mysql_query("select * from cpl_rate_mast where desg='HSKD' and state='MN'");
                $rate=mysql_result($sql_rate,$i,'rate') ;
                $pay=round($present*($rate/$days)); 
            } 

            if(($desgn=='HSKD') && ($state=='MZ')){
                $sql_rate=mysql_query("select * from cpl_rate_mast where desg='HSKD' and state='MZ'");
                $rate=mysql_result($sql_rate,$i,'rate') ;
                $pay=round($present*($rate/$days)); 
            }

            mysql_query("insert into  cpl_pay(billno,ticketno,name,desg,sex,fathersname,day_present,total_wages,from_date,to_date,status,state) values('$vrno','$ticket','$empname','$desgn','$cat','$father','$present','$pay','$fdate1','$tdate2','Y','$state' )  ") or die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: You are making this really manually.  You could fairly easily make this a class or function with much less lines. Anytime you repeat the same code over and over, tells you you need to rework it.

Comment: This code also is open to SQL injections. Don't pass user input directly into a SQL query.

Comment: can you please show an example of functions of above code

Answer (score 2):

Here is a quick demonstration of my comment, which is to rework your script if you find you are copying and pasting same-code throughout a page. You don't seem to have all the variables in your snippit, so I can't guarantee it will work as is. Side note, you need to switch to `PDO` or `mysqli_` for your database connection:

```
<?php
function FetchCPL($array = false)
    {
        $rate   =   0;
        $design =   (!empty($array['design']))? mysql_real_escape_string($array['design']) : false;
        $state  =   (!empty($array['state']))? mysql_real_escape_string($array['state']) : false;
        $count  =   (!empty($array['count']) && is_numeric($array['count']))? $array['count'] : 1;

        if($design && $state) {
                $sql_rate   =   mysql_query("select * from `cpl_rate_mast` where `desg` = '".$design."' and `state` = '".$state."'");
                $rate       =   mysql_result($sql_rate,$i,'rate') ;
            }

         return $rate;
    }

    if(!empty($_POST['u'])) {
            foreach ($_POST['u'] as $uid) {
                    $sql    =   mysql_query("select * from `cpl_pay_temp` where `id` = '".mysql_real_escape_string($uid)."'");

                    while ($cal = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {
                            $empdesg    =   $cal['desg'];
                            $pay        =   round($present*(FetchCPL(array("design"=>$cal['desg'],"state"=>$cal['state'], "count"=>$i))/$days));    
                            mysql_query("insert into  `cpl_pay`
                                (`billno`,`ticketno`,`name`,`desg`,`sex`,`fathersname`,`day_present`,`total_wages`,`from_date`,`to_date`,`status`,`state`) 
                                values('$vrno','".$cal['ticketno']."','".$cal['name']."','".$cal['desg']."','".$cal['sex']."','".$cal['fathersname']."','".$cal['day_present']."','$pay','$fdate1','$tdate2','Y','".$cal['state']."' )  ") or die(mysql_error());
                        }
                }
        }
?>
```

Comment: OMG its magic..ur my savior..its doing absolutely fine..thanks a lot

Comment: every thing is right ..a little problem in days counting from_date to to_date it is calculating 30 days between 21-08-2015 to 20-09-2015 which should be 31 days. the code is made like this `$days = floor( ( strtotime( $todate) - strtotime( $fmdate ) ) / 86400 )+1; `

Comment: Is this a separate issue from what my script is attempting to do?

Comment: sorry the date will be 21-07-2015 to 20-08-2015 showing as 30 days instead of 31 days

Comment: Let me try what you have, but If you mark my answer correct, no one will come to try and solve this issue since it's solved.

Comment: I just tried your code and it says 31 days. It's probably dependent on timezone so depending on your timezone it may be different. My timezone is `America/Los_Angeles`.